# USPTO online filing fees

Tags: filing

What is the fees for **online filing** of a patent application in USPTO, by an individual who is not a US citizen, assuming the patent is already filed in the native country?

Answer (score 3):

The current USPTO fee schedule can be found here ==> http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/qs/ope/fee010114.htm

You will have to pay a basic filing fee, a search fee and an examination fee, presumably at the small entity or micro entity rate.  Note that additional fees are required if you have greater than three independent claims or greater than twenty total claims.

Citizenship of the inventor(s) and whether there is a priority application do not affect the fees.